# Want to get redirect URL after sending post Curl request

Tags: php, laravel, curl, libcurl

I am sending a basic auth request to a site to log in a user. If they credentials are correct I want to show the dashboard. Therefore I need the redirectURL coming in "redirect_url" under "+curl: curl resource @212 ▼"

This is my code. And I want to get the redirect url in $redirectUrl [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1XUS.png)

```
$curl = new Curl\Curl();
$curl->post('https://xyz.ryver.com/application/login', array(
    'username' => 'xyza@xyz.com',
    'password' => 'mypass',
));

$redirectUrl= ""; //store redirecting URL here
return redirect($redirectUrl);
```

I want to get this "redirect_url"'s value [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDrpb.png)

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: Please copy paste your code into question because the links to images or other sites may vanish!

Comment: Right I have added them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
return redirect()->away('https://www.your_url_here.com');
```

Hope this help.

Comment: if i do this it redirects me to the page fine but shows me the login portal as if the user never logged in. The above credentials being true does not show me dashboard upon redirect. Any help there?

Comment: You login in another system after that you want to redirect to dashboard page?. now your problem occur after you login success but when you redirect to dashboard you system ask you for login again?.
If your answer is yes, I think you system have some code for check session of user so you need to keep user in the session after you login success before you force redirect.